# Is there anything fundamentally different between these two representations of an infinite square well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

The first representation is what I would say the more typical one:

$$V(x) = \cases{0 & 0<x<a \\ \infty &else} $$

But it could also be:

$$V(x) =\cases{-\infty & 0<x<a \\ 0 &else} $$

I guess the obvious problem is that we can't introduce an infinity in the Schrödinger equation, so the second case is not an useful description. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi agaminon. Have you tried to calculate the ground state energy in the 2 cases?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not yet, guess I'll be doing that right now. I expect the second case is not going to be possible since $V$ inside the box is infinite.

Comment: This might be the simplest case of renormalization?

Comment: @JEB Ohh, that I think is a really good way to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Handwavy explanation

You're shifting the zero of the potential, so the physical situation is unchanged. The energy eigenvalues $E_n$ are measured from the bottom of the well, so you have "infinite" eigenvalues as the shift from the former case is infinite

### More mathematical explanation

The infinite square well potential is a shortcut to say that the wavefunction is identically zero outside a given region; inside such region there is a *constant* potential $V_0$, which can be set to zero with an appropriate shift$^1$. The expression
$$V(x)=\begin{cases} V_0=0\qquad x\in[0,a] \\
+\infty \qquad \text{outside}
\end{cases}$$
really means that solving the TISE
$$\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(x)\right]\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$$
you have to look for an eigenfunction such that$^1$
$$\psi(x)=0 \qquad x<0\ \lor x>a $$
and
$$\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+\underbrace{V(x)}_{V_0=0}\right]\psi(x)=E\psi(x)\qquad 0<x<a$$
After solving in this region, of course you have to impose the appropriate boundary conditions
$$\psi(0)=\psi(a)=0$$
which give you the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian.
The eigenstates we're finding are the Fourier modes over the interval $[0,a]$ and the completeness of such set amounts to saying that any (wave)function over $[0,a]$ satisfying $\Psi(0)=\Psi(a)=0$ can be expanded in a Fourier series
$$\Psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}c_n\psi_n(x).$$

---

$^1$ <sub>(Handwaving alert again, this note is by no means rigourous and serves the only purpose to make things clear). $V_0$ can be chosen to be any number you want with an appropriate shift, which won't affect the infinite potential outside. If the shift is such that it makes the potential zero outside and infinitely negative inside, then you'll have to deal with an infinite potential (which makes no sense to put in the TISE) in the relevant region, as the outside region cannot be accessed and there is nothing to solve there.</sub>

$^2$ <sub>In fact we do not solve the TISE in the outside region at all.</sub>

Comment: How would you deal with the second potential, though? I understand that they represent the same concept, but mathematically it seems impossible to deal with the second potential within the regiion of interest.

Comment: Maybe I didn't stress it enough. You want to avoid that case, as it makes no sense to put an "infinite potential" inside the TISE. If you really care about, think of it this way: solve the first case and  then do the shift  (or solve the second case with $V_0$ and then take the limit), as I said that would "add an infinite constant" to all eigenvalues, how do you deal with this? The whole "infinite" thing is a shortcut to say what I explained the second paragraph, which is the correct way to think about it.

Comment: Alright, I suppose my intuition was correct then. Thank you!